# BQ PY Client Library : API Explorer & Stackdriver Logging discrepency

Tags: python, google-bigquery

(First of all thanks for reading through my lengthy query)

I'm learning BQ APIs using PY Client libraries.

After creating the client `bigquery.Client()` >> inserting a query job request `client.query(sql)`, i'm issuing following command to check if job has finished:

```
job.done()
```

When I check API Explorer:

1. I can see a method call `bigquery.jobs.get` being made - so far, so good.. I believe that's the API call to refresh the job status!
   [image]
2. but when I switch *Traffic* drop down >> *By credentials*, it reports additional API request by some **Unspecified** credentials.

> Can someone clarify what's this Credential, and what additional API method call this credential is making and if it's included in project
>   API quotas?

(surprisingly, this additional call only reported when segmenting Traffic either *By response code* or *By credentials*, and not when segmenting *By API method* or *By API version*)
[image]

3. I was expecting additional method call `bigquery.jobs.getQueryResults`, because when I look at the GH code, calling `job.done()` would call [`self._client._get_query_results`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/37675843fb59c109591b725b4dd66e1498c534f3/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py#L2461), which seems to make this [additional API call](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/37675843fb59c109591b725b4dd66e1498c534f3/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L559).

> Can someone clarify why I don't see this method call in API Explorer being reported ?

I looked at Stackdriver Logging as well...

4. > Can someone clarify why it does not show the log for #1** (I expected `protoPayload.methodName` =  `jobservice.get` or something similar corresponding to API method `bigquery.jobs.get`), instead it only shows me log for #3 (`protoPayload.methodName` =  `jobservice.getqueryresults`)

[image]

UPDATE: I notice its always a call to `bigquery.tabledata.list` (called during `job.result()`?!) that API Explorer reports under **Unspecified** client name.. also I notice calls to `bigquery.jobs.get` (called during `job.done()`?!) are not being logged to StackDriver

Comment: Hi. Could you provide a snippet code of the python script you are executing to do the API calls?

Comment: Here's GH link: https://github.com/vibhorj/gcp/blob/master/gcp/bq/query.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. bigquery.jobs.get "returns information about a specific job" [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get).
2. There is a public issue, opened recently, about unspecified credentials that you can follow [[2]](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111450671). If this unspecified credentials using any resource quotable [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas), it might effect your project's quota.
3. Because it may depend on which client id you've used for making the API calls. If you haven't specified a service account or a custom client id, the "additional API calls" you mentioned may not appear in your project's API dashboard.
4. This might happen because the execution of bigquery.jobs.get might happened outside of your project, this is related with the #3.

I encourage you to visit Stackdriver's web page [[4]](https://app.google.stackdriver.com/), and access to the Metrics Explorer. Choose "Consumed API" as resource type, and "Request" for the Metric; you will see an alternative representation of method calls.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response! this clarifies a lot.